# Learning how to use Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

I've recently started my second course in Quantum Theory and am now often required to prove more complex commutation relations. I'm aware that the [Levi-Civita symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) often makes this sort of thing a lot slicker, but I'm finding it really hard to crack. There are some great answers to individual queries relating to it online, but I was wondering if anyone knew of somewhere (book, site etc.) I could learn how to use it from the ground up? Maybe with exercises/solutions?

Comment: Are you aware of the techniques of *tensor calculus*? A quick google search on this topic may help you along quite a bit, although you're at risk of spending a lot of time learning all the details of this formalism :D

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not. My degree is in Mathematics and I've mainly done pure but chose Quantum for a bit of variety. Would that be the best place to start?

Comment: Maybe you need to look at an intro GR book - there is a lot more tensor calculus in such courses, so it will give you a better introduction. Check out the first couple chapters of Sean Carroll's review article: http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019, or the text that grew out of it.

Comment: Oh also the first chapter of Landau's EM book has a footnote which contains some Levi-Civita stuff. I know that sounds obscure, but it's actually the first place I always go to when I need to know something about it!

Comment: Levi-Civita symbol for **commutation relations?** In which theory?